# How to retrieve a queryset using any/exists/all logic across foreign key relationships in Django?

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, filtering

Assuming I have two models:

```
from django.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='children')
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

How might I go about getting a query set of parents that have at least 1 active child? In other words, how would I get a query set of parents that excludes those without any active children?  If using model properties in filters was feasible, this would be a trivial task, but that is not possible.  This is also a simple operation using list comprehensions, but it's important here for the queryset to be the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use aggregation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/

We can annotate a queryset of parents with the number of active children they have, and then filter against that queryset to only find parents with a number greater than or equal to 0:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

num_active_children = Count('children', filter=Q(children__active=True))
parents_with_any_active_children = (Parent.objects
    .annotate(num_active_children=num_active_children)
    .filter(num_active_children__gte=1)
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is uses the resources Django gives you with querysets.

Answer (score 0):

Parent.objects.filter(child__active=True)

Hope this is enough for you.